# how can I read list of object of array

Tags: angular

how can I read with ngfor unter

```
lebens = [
   {
     lebenslage: "Arbeit & Ruhestand",
     kata: [
       {
        unter: "altervorsorge",
        unterunter: [
          "Erbschein",
          "Zusätzliche Altersvorsorgeförderung",
          "Urkundenverwahrung und -registrierung"
        ]
       },
       {
          unter: "Arbeitsplatzwechsel",
          unterunter: [
            "Gesundheitszeugnis",
            "Zulassung für reglementierte Berufe",
            "Anerkennung akademischer Abschlüsse"
          ]
         }

    ]
   },
   {
    lebenslage: "Bauen & Wohnen",
    kata: [
      {
        unter: "Wohnen & Umzug",
        unterunter: [
          "Abfallentsorgung",
          "Baumfällgenehmigung",
          "Rundfunkbeitrag"
        ]
      },
      {
        unter: "Bauen & Immobilien",
        unterunter: [
          "Abbruchgenehmigung",
          "Baulastenverzeichnis",
          "Denkmalförderung"
        ]
      }
    ]
   } 
  ]
```

Comment: how you want to display them? what you have tried so far?

Comment: Did you check angular docs ? https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data

Comment: yes i can easily read lebenslage but in kata -> i cant read unter because there are other one array and in this array one other object

Comment: @ChintanVaghani have you check my answer ? 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use nested `ngFor` depend of you data level

```html
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let l of lebens">
    {{l.lebenslage}}
    <ol>
      <li *ngFor="let k of l.kata">
          {{k.unter }}
          <div>
            <span  *ngFor="let unterunter of k.unterunter"> {{unterunter}}</span>
          </div>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ul>
```

[demo ⚡⚡](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mxrnyc)

Comment: yes its work very good. can you also tell me please how can i filter unter ?